# The sheaf propagation is open in the zero section

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, cohomology, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ a smooth manifold and $F$ a sheaf (let's say of abelian groups) on $X$. We will say that $F$ propagates at $x\in X$ in the (co)-direction $p \in T_x^*X$ if for all $C^1$-function $\phi$ defined in a neighborhood of $x$ with $\phi(x)=0$ and $d\phi(x) = p$, the natural map $$\varinjlim_{U\ni x} H^j(U,F) \to \varinjlim_{U\ni x} H^j(U\cap \{\phi<0\},F)$$ is an isomorphism for all $j$.

Then we define the micro-support of $F$ (noted $SS(F)$) as the closure of the set of couples $(x,p)$ where propagation does not occur.

This concept is still a bit nebulous for me and I struggle with one of the most simple fact about it.

> If $(x,0) \notin SS(F)$ (in particular, $F$ propagates at $(x,0)$) then $F$ propagates at $(y,0)$ for $y$ near $x$.

How can we prove this statement, just with the definition ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think that $SS(F)$ is usually defined as the closure of couples where there is no propagation.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that what you try to prove is true:

Propagation at $(x,0)$ is equivalent to $\varinjlim_{x\in U}H^j(U,F)=0$ (because we can take $\phi>0$ in the complement of $x$, hence $U\cap\{\phi<0\}=\emptyset$)

So for instance, the constant sheaf on $(-\infty,0)$ propagates at $(0,0)$ but does not propagate at $(-\varepsilon,0)$ for all $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: You're right, the assumption needs to be a little stronger. We have to assume that $(x,0) \notin SS(F)$. (So in your exemple, we can't consider $(0,0)$)

Comment: With this new consideration, the problem becomes trivial. Thank you for pointing out my imprecision with the definition. Now it becomes clear.